# Share controllers in 2 projects of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two virtualhost on a server. Each virtualhost has a laravel project installed (Project 1 and Project 2)

In Project 1 I have configured an API.

Can I call API methods from Project 2 without having to make an API call (guzzle or http request)? Directly accessing the controller of project 1?

thxs

I can't find how to call a controller from another Laravel project

Comment: If you just need to send request to two servers with same controller you maybe looking for traffic shadowing/mirroring you can achieve such behavior using Istio or other instruments. But if you're trying to reuse this controller from code, maybe you should consider to extract your business logic into separate repository/package and use it in your controller from Project 1?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot call API methods from Project 2 without making a call using Guzzle or HTTP requests.

If you try to call the methods directly from Project 2, without making an API call, you will run into various issues, such as security vulnerabilities.

It's not recommended but, if you want such access, you can do it like this:

```php
include_once('/path/to/Project1/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php');

$controller = new Controller();
$controller->method();
```

Comment: and is it possible to make an API call from project 1 to project 2 without the request leaving the server? Because the two projects are on the same server and thus we optimize response times

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's no straightforward way to handle this because the code of each project lives in its own namespace, so you can't directly access the other controller.

However, you can try communication between the two projects through IPC (Inter-Process Communication)

> In computer science, inter-process communication or interprocess communication (IPC) refers specifically to the mechanisms an operating system provides to allow the processes to manage shared data. (source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

If you're using services classes to handle business logic instead of writing all the code inside the controller, then you can proceed to create a [custom artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#generating-commands) that will invoke the adjacent method inside the service class, and in case you need to pass parameters then you can do this as well passing them one-by-one or serializing them into a JSON string that gets sent as a single parameter, and the receiving command will parse it and extract the data.

For example, let's say that the ***first project*** has a command that extracts username from a string as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ExtractUsername extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'app:extract-username {user}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Extracts username from a JSON string';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $user = $this->argument("user");
        $info = json_decode($user);
        $this->line($info->username);
    }
}
```

Now, in order to call it from within the ***second project***, you can use the `Process` facade that's available under the namespace `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Process`, it returns an instance of `Illuminate\Process\ProcessResult` which you can call the `output()` method to get the output of the process, here's an example:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Process;

$processResult = Process::run("php /absolute/path/to/second/project/artisan app:extract-username '{\"username\": \"Someone\" }'");

$output = $processResult->output(); // "Someone"
```

Please notice that the `run()` method is **synchronous** (i.e. it blocks execution of the script until the forked process terminates)

For asynchronous behavior, consult the `start()` method in Laravel documentation about [Processes management](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/processes#asynchronous-processes)

I hope I've made the answer clear and understandable

Comment: Thxs Eyad, and is it possible to make an API call from project 1 to project 2 without the request leaving the server? Because the two projects are on the same server and thus we optimize response times